# Zerar um array dinâmico - ReDim ou Erase?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, listbox

Tenho um `UserForm` com três `OptionButton` e três `ListBox`.

Ao abrir o `UserForm` os três `ListBox` são carregados com textos diferentes, pois cada uma se relaciona com um tipo de dado conforme está explícito em cada `OptionButton`.

Nos `ListBox` é permitido selecionar mais do que uma opção.

Os `ListBox` ficam desabilitados na abertura do `UserForm`.

Ao clicar no primeiro `OptionButton`, o código a ele referente retira as seleções (se houver) dos outros `ListBox`, e desabilita-os, o mesmo irá ocorrer se clicar em um dos outros `OptionButton`.

Clicando no botão ATUALIZAR, o código do mesmo verifica qual `OptionButton` está ativo, e percorre o `ListBox` correspondente preenchendo uma matriz (array) dinâmica com o nome dos textos selecionados.

O código funciona perfeitamente, já bem testado. Minha dúvida: clicando em qualquer um dos `OptionButton`, o array tem que ser esvaziado e estar sem tamanho para ser preenchido novamente do zero, e portanto posso usar `ReDim(0)` ou `Erase Array`.

Qual dos dois devo usar?

Segundo pesquisas na internet, acredito que seja `Erase`, pois as informações são de que limpa a memória para utilizar o array de novo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Erase normalmente é usado antes do redim, já que o último redimensiona o vetor mantendo os valores.

Comment: OK. Agradecido pela resposta.
Mas eu quero não somente apagar os dados do array, mas também redimensioná-lo para zero.

Comment: Somente o Erase é suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

#### ReDim e Erase

O melhor seria seguir a semântica, para que outra pessoa que leia o código ou você mesmo consiga entender com mais facilidade e ajude na manutenção do código no futuro.

Então a função [ReDim](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) é utilizada para dimensionar ou redimensionar uma matriz dinâmica e [Erase](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/erase-statement) para liberar variáveis de matriz e desalocar a memória usada para seus elementos.

Além de que o ReDim não pode ser utilizado em Arrays estáticas, já o Erase é utilizado em ambos casos (estático e dinâmico).

#### Exemplo

Veja o seguinte exemplo do SOen, para verificar que a única diferença está em Arrays dinâmicos:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128773/7690982
Dim NumArray(10) As Integer ' Integer array.
Erase NumArray ' Each element set to 0.

Dim StrVarArray(10) As String ' Variable-string array.
Erase StrVarArray ' Each element set to zero-length string ("").    

Dim StrFixArray(10) As String * 10 ' Fixed-string array.
Erase StrFixArray ' Each element set to 0.

Dim VarArray(10) As Variant ' Variant array.
Erase VarArray ' Each element set to Empty.

Dim DynamicArray() As Integer ' Dynamic array.
ReDim DynamicArray(10) ' Allocate storage space.
Erase DynamicArray ' Free memory used by array.

Dim DynamicArray2() As Integer ' Dynamic array.
ReDim DynamicArray2(10) ' Allocate storage space.
ReDim DynamicArray2(0) ' Allocate storage space.
```

O resultado na janela de Variáveis Locais para cada array:

- NumArray:

[image: NumArray]

- StrVarArray:

[image: StrVarArray]

- StrFixArray:

[image: StrFixArray]

- VarArray:

[image: VarArray]

- DynamicArray:

[image: DynamicArray]

- DynamicArray2:

[image: DynamicArray2]